# Breaking up underlying binary in Byte array into 10 or 12 bit words: C#

Tags: c#, arrays, binary, byte

I'm parsing binary data from a file that comes in as a byte array. I'm trying to split the underlying binary of the array into 'words' (every 10 or 12 bits). I have a function that does this but it is pretty time consuming as I'm dealing with a lot of data. I have limited programming experience so I'm sure there's a better way to accomplish this.

```
private void separateWords(List<byte[]> minorFrames, int wordSize, int frameLength)
{
    UInt16[] wordArray = new UInt16[frameLength];

    foreach (byte[] array in minorFrames)
    {
        // Convert byte array to bit array
        // Bits need to be reversed on a byte boundary
        byte[] temp = new byte[array.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = ReverseBits(array[i]);
        }
        BitArray binaryArray = new BitArray(temp);

        for (int i = 0; i < (binaryArray.Length / wordSize); i++ )
        {
            UInt16 newWord = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < wordSize; j++)
            { // Converts every n bits to UInt16 
                if (binaryArray[j + (i*wordSize)])
                    newWord += Convert.ToUInt16(Math.Pow(2, ((wordSize-1)-j)));
            }
            wordArray[i]=newWord; // Populate formatted minor frame
        }
        words.Add(wordArray); // add populated minor frame to lsit
    }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to operate directly on the byte array. The 'words' will be saved into UInt16's to keep the output size as small as possible.

My current thought is:

- Shift first 10 bits into UInt16 variable
- add variable to array of words
- shift entire byte array over 10 bits
- repeat

I'm having some trouble shifting bits into a UInt16 though, and unsure how to shift an entire array. Maybe there's a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

`Math.Pow` is very time consuming. Consider using [Bitwise and shift operators (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators).

```
if (binaryArray[j + i * wordSize]) {
    newWord |= (ushort)(1 << (wordSize - 1 - j));
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked, but also sparked a new idea to simplify it even further.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

After some feedback I've rewritten the loop to:

```
public List<UInt16[]> separateWords(List<byte[]> minorFrames, int wordSize, int frameLength)
{
    List<UInt16[]> framedWords = new List<UInt16[]>();
    UInt16 newWord = 0;

    foreach (byte[] array in minorFrames)
    {
        int bitcount = 1;
        int wordCount = 0;
        BitArray binaryArray = new BitArray(array);
        UInt16[] wordArray = new UInt16[frameLength];

        for (int i = 1; i <= array.Length; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j <= 8; j++)
            {   
                newWord <<= 1;                                              // Make room for next bit
                newWord |= Convert.ToUInt16(binaryArray[(i * 8) - j]);      // Adds next bit in array
                if (bitcount % wordSize == 0)       // Only if multiple of wordsize
                {
                    wordArray[wordCount] = newWord; // Populate formatted minor frame
                    newWord = 0;                    // Reset for next word
                    wordCount++;                    // Advance index
                }
                bitcount++;
            }
        }
        framedWords.Add(wordArray); // add populated minor frame to lsit
    }
    return framedWords;
}
```

This took the run time from 12 minutes to 2.5 minutes.